# About Tool Strip Status in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change the text in the Tool Strip Status from one message to another message in 2 second. Why can't I do like below?

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Cool";
Thread.Sleep(2000);
toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status: IP Address update complete";
```

I've tried it but it only display the second message. Why it doesn't display the first message while within the 2 second?

Comment: Is this a web page ? maybe, and just maybe, without seen all of your code, you set the first tooltip, then sleep for 2 seconds, and then set the new toolstrip.. and then finish load page and of course, you only will see the second text. You lost the 2 seconds in your code(make the first line, the second line, wait two seconds and there do the third line)

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

rather than just sleeping. The app needs to process the refresh/draw/paint events that are triggered and waiting.

Comment: Actually, I want to show the status of my serial port transmitting. The steps are something like this: 1) Click button. 2) Show status label as "transmitting". 3) Do serial port transmitting which is around 2 second. 4) Show status label as "transmit complete". How do I do all this?

Comment: Calling application.DoEvents will achieve the result your wanting however i would not recommend this as a solution.  There are better approaches to updating the UI.  You are probably going to want to look into Task or Backgroundworker and move your serial port transmitting off the UI thread.